# How to stop Yarn Package Manager script from CLI

Tags: node.js, linux, yarnpkg

https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/

Is there a way to stop what is started from the command `yarn run`? Is my only option to lookup the process number and call `kill` on it?

Comment: what's wrong with pressing `ctrl-c`?

Comment: maybe I am just too much of a linux noob, but when I run yarn start the process is  hidden. Maybe it is in the background? I am looking for a one command action to stop what I started.

Comment: Ctrl-C can be an ungraceful way to exit. I always check the docs first to make sure its a safe way to quit a program I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The usual way `ctrl-c` should work. If it doesn't work, than you have bug in the script. The script's author missed handler for shutdown (SIGINT/SIGTERM/etc).

Comment: I must have confused myself coming back in from the weekend. ctrl-c is all I need.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a well-answered question. However, it behaved once very strange when I was running a sample React code which was auto-created by the `create-react-app` CLI, on my Windows 10.

After hitting `Ctrl+C`, which is the most suggested standard way to stop the `yarn run`, though I got back the command prompt, there was a ghost process lingering around there, which was still actively listening to 3000(default) port, and `localhost:3000` was working as normal.

So finally this is how I fixed it:

- `netstat -ano | grep ":3000"` (yeah, I ran this from my git-bash instead of command prompt!)
- Noted down the `PID` of the line where it says `LISTENING` on 3000
- Pressed `Ctrl+Shift+Esc` to open the Task Manager
- Went to the Process tab
- Right clicked on one of the headings, say Name
- Selected PID --> This added the PID column to the display
- Located the PID in question
- Right clicked on it and clicked "End task"

Luckily Windows knew how to kill that misbehaving, ghost process and the port became free for me.

NOTE: Prior to the above-mentioned steps, I tried to kill that PID from git-bash using the famous (or notorious as per its meaning?? >8)) `kill -9` command. It was responding back with no such PID msg, however `netstat -ano` was clearly displaying the PID and browser was proving that the ghost process is up and alive!!

Comment: Same thing for me, residual ghost process after ^C. (Coincidentally port 3000.) I had to include `-p` among the netstat options to see the PID: `netstat -apno ...`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue having it running after ctl+c and then I thought, maybe it is just running on the cache

so went to http://localhost:3000/

> ctrl+F5

which forces refresh without cache showed me that the actual project wasn't really running anymore!

;)

*hadn't it worked I would have had to sudo kill the 3000 port